# Observing Changes to Struct Swift

Tags: swift, struct, observable, viewmodel

I want my MVVM architecture to have a class as the model and a struct as the view model or view controller. This is because I want to re-init a bunch of properties with changes to the model and using a class as the view model only allows one init. However, it haven't found a way for views to observe new structs / changes to structs in the view model.

Example of my problem:

```
class Model: ObservableObject {
    var nums: [Int]
    
    init() {
        self.nums = Array(1..<100)
    }
    
    func getNum() -> Int {
        return nums.count
    }
    
    func add() {
        nums.append(nums.count + 1)
        self.objectWillChange.send()
    }
}

struct ViewModel {
    var model: Model
    var num: Int
    
    init(model: Model) {
        self.model = model
        self.num = model.getNum()
    }
    
    func trigger() {
        model.add()
        print("Triggered")
        
    }
}



struct ContentView: View {
    var viewModel: ViewModel
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {viewModel.trigger() }) {
            Text("Press")
        }
        Text("Number of Elements")
        Text("\(viewModel.num)")
    }
    
}

var model = Model()
var viewModel = ViewModel(model: model)
var view = ContentView(viewModel: viewModel)


@main
struct app: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            view
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `ViewModel`'s initializer mutates the `Model`. That seems bad. Why should displaying the number of friends modify the number of friends?

Comment: As the above comment alludes to, this seems like a strange example. `num` never gets mutated outside of the initializer to the view model. I'm confused as to what the desired behavior is here. In general, this approach is the opposite of the traditional path of your model being a `struct` and your view model being a `class`

Comment: I've edited the example to avoid mutating array in init

Comment: Num does get mutated at the view level by the button

Comment: No, it doesn't. `nums` does.

Comment: The desired behavior here is to have a view model that inits itself with changes to the model, as in my real example it makes since to compute the properties of the view model once in the init

Comment: right, but increasing nums should change num--the number of elements

Comment: or at least I want it to

Comment: Okay. That's fighting an uphill battle and going against all of the conventions. Is there a reason you want to buck convention and go this unusual route?

Comment: In my opinion your `Model` should be a `struct` in the the first place. Then you don't need an observer. Once you set something, the `struct` has changed and a `didSet` will be called on the property that holds it.

Comment: How would you do what I'm trying to do within conventions? If I use a class I can't init again with changes to the model. I want to compute properties in init because I can save the properties to use in multiple methods

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would solve this if your main goal is getting properties calculated on the view model based on changes to the model:

```
import Combine

struct Model {
    var nums: [Int]
    
    init() {
        self.nums = Array(1..<100)
    }
    
    func getNum() -> Int {
        return nums.count
    }

    //note there aren't mutating methods here
}

class ViewModel : ObservableObject {
    @Published var model: Model
    @Published var num: Int = -1
    
    private var cancellable : AnyCancellable?
    
    init(model: Model) {
        self.model = model
        cancellable = $model.sink(receiveValue: { newValue in
            self.num = newValue.getNum() //calculated based on the new value
        })
    }
    
    func trigger() {
        self.add()
        print("Triggered")
    }
    
    //mutating method here
    func add() {
        model.nums.append(model.nums.count + 1)
    }
}



struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel: ViewModel = ViewModel(model: Model())
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {viewModel.trigger() }) {
            Text("Press")
        }
        Text("Number of Elements")
        Text("\(viewModel.num)")
    }
    
}
```

---

Update, if you want the mutating functions in the model:

```
struct Model {
    var nums: [Int]
    
    init() {
        self.nums = Array(1..<100)
    }
    
    func getNum() -> Int {
        return nums.count
    }

    mutating func add() {
        nums.append(nums.count + 1)
    }
}

class ViewModel : ObservableObject {
    @Published var model: Model
    @Published var num: Int = -1
    
    private var cancellable : AnyCancellable?
    
    init(model: Model) {
        self.model = model
        cancellable = $model.sink(receiveValue: { newValue in
            self.num = newValue.getNum() //calculated based on the new value
        })
    }
    
    func trigger() {
        model.add()
        print("Triggered")
    }
}
```

Comment: Do we need to have the mutating method in the viewModel? In my real problem the mutating logic is complex enough that I want to encapsulate it in the model (or what I'm calling the model, I'm not dealing with API requests, etc at this point).

Comment: See my update. Personally, I wouldn't approach it this way, as it's somewhat unconventional, but it can be done.

Comment: As an improvement, I would not leak Model through the ViewModel (instead, publish a dedicated struct containing all relevant state for the view), and provide actions methods in the view model (called from the UI) which in turn may mutate an underlying model. How mutation is performed is then an implementation detail of the ViewModel.

Answer (score 0):

well, the first thing I think I see is that you put the observable object in your model, and in mvvm it tries to put that property in the view model because it needs to be reactive,a model only receives some properties, you could change the property to its view model and be able to make it reactive.

It doesn't matter if you use a class as a model, it still works, that's to your liking.

```
class Model{
var nums: [Int]

init() {
    self.nums = Array(1..<100)
}

func getNum() -> Int {
    return nums.count
}

func add() {
    nums.append(nums.count + 1)
    self.objectWillChange.send()
}
}

 struct ViewModel:ObservableObject  {

var model: Model
var num: Int

init(model: Model) {
    self.model = model
    self.num = model.getNum()
}

func trigger() {
    model.add()
    print("Triggered")
    
}
 }



struct ContentView: View {
@observedObject var viewModel: ViewModel 
var body: some View {
    Button(action: {viewModel.trigger() }) {
        Text("Press")
    }
    Text("Number of Elements")
    Text("\(viewModel.num)")
}

 }

   var model = Model()
   var viewModel = ViewModel(model: model)
  var view = ContentView(viewModel: viewModel)


  @main
  struct app: App {
    var body: some Scene {
       WindowGroup {
         view
     }
 }
  }
```

Comment: structs can't conform to ObservableObject, right?

Comment: yes it can conform  it don't have any problem

Comment: No, a `struct` cannot conform to `ObservableObject`. [`ObservableObject`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/observableobject#) inherits `AnyObject`, which means only classes (and actors) can conform to `ObservableObject`.

Comment: @robmayoff   sorry for that, I had not noticed but you are right, I had never done the test with a class ! 

Answer (score 0):

Here's something that's pretty simple and accomplishes what I want. Instead of using a struct as the view model / controller, use a class--now both the model and view model are classes. The problem with this, of course, is that a class is a reference type and won't re-init unlike a struct, which is created anew with changes. So I don't rely on the init method to set my properties--I update them after I know there's been a change in the `trigger` method of the `ViewModel` class. Here's an example:

```js
class Model {
    var nums: [Int]
    
    init() {
        self.nums = Array(1..<100)
    }
    
    func getNum() -> Int {
        return nums.count
    }
    
    func add() {
        nums.append(nums.count + 1)
    }
}


func updateProperty(model: Model) -> Int {
    return model.getNum()
}


class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    var model: Model
    var num: Int
    
    init(model: Model) {
        self.model = model
        self.num = updateProperty(model: model)
    }
    
    func trigger() {
        model.add()
        self.num = updateProperty(model: self.model)
        self.objectWillChange.send()
    }
}



struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {viewModel.trigger() }) {
            Text("Press")
        }
        Text("Number of Elements")
        Text("\(viewModel.num)")
    }
}

var model = Model()
var viewModel = ViewModel(model: model)
var view = ContentView(viewModel: viewModel)
```

Obviously, in most real situations, the `updateProperty` function will be more complex than just one `Int`